# mysql group_concat group by on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a Table member with `member_id`, `member_name`, `club_name`, `region`, `zone`, `email` as fields.

I am using the MySQL `group_concat` function like

```
SELECT group_concat(distinct m.email
SEPARATOR ', ' ) from member m group by m.club_name
```

This is working fine. But I would like to be able to `group_concat` on other fields without creating additional queries.

Is it possible to supply the other fields as parameter?

```
member_id   member_name club_name   region  zone    email
1           member1           A        1    1   email1@example.com
2           member2           A        1    1   email2@example.com
3           member3           B        1    1   email3@example.com
4           member4           C        1    2   email4@example.com
5           member5           D        2    1   email5@example.com

**group by club**
email1@example.com,email2@example.com
email3@example.com
email4@example.com
email5@example.com

**group by region**
email1@example.com, email2@example.com, email3@example.com, email4@example.com
email5@example.com

**group by zone**
email1@example.com, email2@example.com, email3@example.com
email5@example.com
```

Say every Region has 3 Zones, every zone has more than one club. Now how can I get emails which can be grouped or related to Region, Zone or Club for that matter?

Comment: Please add your desired result set

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple GROUP\_CONCAT on different fields using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506750/multiple-group-concat-on-different-fields-using-mysql)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to understand what are you after exactly from your question but you can try

```sql
SELECT club_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email SEPARATOR ', ' ) emails,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT member_name SEPARATOR ', ' ) members
       ... 
 FROM member
GROUP BY club_name
```

Sample output:

```
| CLUB_NAME |                                EMAILS |          MEMBERS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Club1 | m1@mail.com, m2@mail.com, m3@mail.com | Jhon, Mark, Beth |
|     Club2 |              m4@mail.com, m5@mail.com |    Helen, Thomas |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e3e1/1)** demo

**On a side note:** *providing sample data and desired output in a question like this usually improves your changes of getting your answer faster and that best fits your needs.*

**UPDATE:** You can deeply pack information using `GROUP_CONCAT()` using different separators if it's what you want

```sql
SELECT 'club' group_type, GROUP_CONCAT(details SEPARATOR '|') details
  FROM
(
  SELECT CONCAT(club_name, ';', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email)) details
    FROM member
   GROUP BY club_name
) a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'region' group_type, GROUP_CONCAT(details SEPARATOR '|') details
  FROM
(
  SELECT CONCAT(region, ';', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email)) details
    FROM member
   GROUP BY region
) a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'zone' group_type, GROUP_CONCAT(details SEPARATOR '|') details
  FROM
(
  SELECT CONCAT(zone, ';', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email)) details
    FROM member
   GROUP BY zone
) a
```

Sample output:

```
| GROUP_TYPE |                                                                                                DETAILS |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       club | A;email1@example.com,email2@example.com|B;email3@example.com|C;email4@example.com|D;email5@example.com |
|     region |     1;email1@example.com,email2@example.com,email3@example.com,email4@example.com|2;email5@example.com |
|       zone |     1;email1@example.com,email2@example.com,email3@example.com,email5@example.com|2;email4@example.com |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0318d/7)** demo

If you're using php on the client side you can then easily enough unwind `details` column into separate records using `explode()` while you're iterating over the resultset.

Comment: I have put the complete example above now, what exactly I want.

Comment: @Pawan What do you mean by *...supply other fields as parameter...*? You can always group by any of these fields specifying it in `GROUP BY`... Or you want get emails grouped by different fields in one resultset (one row per grouping)?

Comment: Can you elaborate how I can have emails grouped by different fields in one resultset i.e. what I want and can't see it. though it might seem obvious to you.

Comment: I think one row per grouping what I am looking for.

Comment: @Pawan See updated answer. I made an example. But once again, until you come to terms with yourself what you need exactly and in what form it's very hard to help you shooting in the dark.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure I will be able to adept your example at JSFidde to my needs.