# Bind multiple columns in an array/struct with a single table

Tags: json, sqlite, orm, go

I would like to use an orm. I looked at [here](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Projects#ORM) to find some orms with documentations. The problem I'm facing is that none of those orms seems to be able to bind multiple columns into an array or a sub-structure.

To be clear, here is an example. I have a table that looks like that :

```
Table User
----------
UserId
UserName
UserPositionX
UserPositionY
UserPositionZ
```

Ideally, I would like to bind the fields into this structure (The array is to be coherent with another API that I'm using client-side) :

```
type User struct {
    Id int64
    Name string
    Position [3]float64
}
```

Where `UserPositionX` binds to `Position[0]`, `UserPositionY` binds to `Position[1]` and `UserPositionZ` binds to `Position[2]`.

I'm open to use a structure like this one instead of an array :

```
type Vector3 struct {
    X, Y, Z float64
}

type User struct {
    Id int64
    Name string
    Position Vector3
}
```

But then I'm facing two problems :

- I don't want to separate the `Position` fields in another table. All orms that I looked seems to consider that 1 struct = 1 table.
- This structure have to be converted (marshalled) into json. In this json, I need the position to be an array (example : `{"id": 42, name: "Foo", position: [6.3, 8.6, 2.65]}`).

So my question is : Is there an available orm for go (and sqlite) that is capable of binding multiple columns in an array or struct without creating another table ? If it's not possible with an array, is there a way to customize how a specific type is marshalled into json ?

---

## EDIT

I found a way to change how a specific type is converted into json. I just need to add two methods to the given type. In this example :

```
func (p *Vector3) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("[%v,%v,%v]", p.X, p.Y, p.Z)), nil
}

func (p *Vector3) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {
    _, err = fmt.Sscanf(string(data), "[%v,%v,%v]", &p.X, &p.Y, &p.Z)
    return
}
```

Result :

```
test, _ := json.Marshal(User{3, "fooBarBaz", Vector3{42.0, 35, 23.45}})
fmt.Println(string(test))
// ==> {"Id":3,"Name":"fooBarBaz","Position":[42.0,35,23.45]}

test2 := User{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Id":3,"Name":"fooBarBaz","Position":[42.0,35,23.45]}`), &test2)
log.Println(test2)
// ==> {3 fooBarBaz {42.0 35 23.45}}
```

My initial problem still exists because I tested some orms in the list and the only thing I found is by embedding structs, and I need the `Vector3` to be an attribute.

Comment: It is btw. completely okay to answer your own questions on SO, in case you didn't knew this.

Comment: @TheHippo I know it, but my edit doesn't answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you need to combine to features of the `database/sql` package and the sql database:

1. You need to group your position columns with `GROUP_CONCAT` to a comma separated list.
2. You need to implement the `sql.Scanner` interface on your type to map the comma separated list to an array.

For the first step you can look at existing [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113803/mysql-group-concat-group-by-on-multiple-fields).

For the second step you could use something like:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar []string
}

func (f *Foo) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch t := src.(type) {
    // t would then equal "value1, value2, value3"
    case string:
        *f = strings.Split(t, ",")

        return nil
    }

    return ErrBadScanType
}
```

[Example](https://github.com/satisfeet/hoopoe-old/blob/sql/model/variation.go#L16-L32) where mapping `key1:value1, key2:value2, ...` to an object.

PS: You should also consider using some special `geo` data type for storing vectors if supported by your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this way is not really optimized.

Comment: @SebastienC. Why is this not optimized?