# How to concat find_in_set results with comma separated string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have used `FIND_IN_SET` to my below select sql query and got the result but I want to store `industrie_branch` comma separated list

### Select Query:

```
SELECT i.instagrammer_id
      , CONCAT(i.first_name,' ',i.last_name) AS instagrammer_name
      , FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), i.date_of_birth)/365) AS age
      , i.date_of_birth
      , i.gender
      , i.email
      , i.created_date
      , b.name_en AS industrie_branch
FROM instagrammer AS i
LEFT JOIN industries_branches b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.industrie_branch_id, i.industrie_branch)
WHERE i.status = 1
ORDER BY instagrammer_name DESC
```

and getting this output of above query:

```
instagrammer_id     instagrammer_name       age     date_of_birth       gender      email               industrie_branch
***************     *****************       ***     *************       ******      ****************    ****************
37                  Jack                    27      1988-09-30          male        jack@hotmail.com    Food
37                  Jack                    27      1988-09-30          male        jack@hotmail.com    Photography
38                  Tom                     27      1988-09-30          male        tom@gmail.com       Lifestyle
38                  Tom                     27      1988-09-30          male        tom@gmail.com       Luxury
```

but I want this output with comma separated list for `industrie_branch`:

```
instagrammer_id     instagrammer_name       age     date_of_birth       gender      email               industrie_branch
***************     *****************       ***     *************       ******      ****************    ****************
37                  Jack                    27      1988-09-30          male        jack@hotmail.com    Food, Photography
38                  Tom                     27      1988-09-30          male        tom@gmail.com       Lifestyle, Luxury
```

Comment: Never store data as comma separated values - it will only cause you lots of trouble. One value/row is the SQL way!

Comment: Send us your mysql data sample using [SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Jarlh is correct. However as a short term hack you can wrap this query up inside another, with GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Just use this thread to get your desired output, not exactly but helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113803/mysql-group-concat-group-by-on-multiple-fields

Comment: but i want to display records to my datatable.

Answer (score 1):

use it like this with GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT i.instagrammer_id
  , CONCAT(i.first_name,' ',i.last_name) AS instagrammer_name
  , FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), i.date_of_birth)/365) AS age
  , i.date_of_birth
  , i.gender
  , i.email
  , i.created_date
  , GROUP_CONCAT(b.name_en) AS industrie_branch
FROM instagrammer AS i
LEFT JOIN industries_branches b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.industrie_branch_id, i.industrie_branch)
WHERE i.status = 1
GROUP BY i.instagrammer_id
ORDER BY instagrammer_name DESC
```