# mysql GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT multiple columns

Tags: mysql, tags

I have a tag field for a blog posts. tags have unique id but their displayName might be duplicated. What I want is a query that selects posts and in `all_tags` field we get couples of (id,displayName) is this way:

```
id1,name1;id2,name2;id3,name3
```

My query looks like:

```
select ....
CONCAT_WS(';', DISTINCT (CONCAT_WS(',',tags.id,tags.displayName))) AS all_tags
Join ...post content ...
Join ...post_tags ...
Join ...tags ...
ORDER BY posts.id
```

This line causes problem:

```
CONCAT_WS(';', DISTINCT (CONCAT_WS(',',tags.id,tags.displayName))) AS all_tags
```

How should I modify it?

Some people use an inner `(SELECT .. FROM)` but as I have heard, it is so inefficien

---

```
SELECT `posts`.*,`categories`.*,`creators`.*,`editors`.*
CONCAT_WS(';', DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',',tags.id,tags.displayName))) AS all_ids
FROM (`posts`) 
LEFT JOIN `languages` ON `posts`.`language_id`=`languages`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` as creators ON `posts`.`creatorUser_id`=`creators`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` as editors ON `posts`.`lastEditorUser_id`=`editors`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `userProfiles` as editors_profile ON `editors`.`profile_id`=`editors_profile`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `posts`.`category_id`=`categories`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `postTags` ON `postTags`.`post_id`=`posts`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `postTags`.`tag_id`=`tags`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `postTags` as `nodetag_checks` ON `nodetag_checks`.`post_id`=`posts`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` as `tag_checks` ON `nodetag_checks`.`tag_id`=`tag_checks`.`id` 
WHERE ( 9 IN(`tag_checks`.`id`,`tag_checks`.`cached_parents`) OR 10 IN(`tag_checks`.`id`,`tag_checks`.`cached_parents`) OR 11 IN(`tag_checks`.`id`,`tag_checks`.`cached_parents`)) 
GROUP BY `posts`.`id` ORDER BY `posts`.`created` desc LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: can we see the whole query? depends on what inner select you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple GROUP\_CONCAT on different fields using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506750/multiple-group-concat-on-different-fields-using-mysql)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Try this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT CONCAT(tags.id,',',tags.displayName) 
  ORDER BY posts.id 
  SEPARATOR ';'
)
```

Comment: You most likely meant `CONCAT(tags.id, ',', tags.displayName)`. Also `GROUP BY post.id` instead of `ORDER BY post.id` are in order.

Comment: @peterm actually no, the op wants a single string returned like "id1,name1;id2,name2;id3,name3..."

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(tags.id,',',tags.displayName) ORDER BY posts.id SEPARATOR ';')`

Comment: @Stephan may I ask you why `ORDER BY` is necessary here?

Comment: @werva i saw it in your query and i thought you wanted the data to be order by post id... you can remove it if its not needed

Comment: Note that if you don't need DISTINCT, you don't need CONCAT, as GROUP_CONCAT is able to concat multiple fields : `GROUP_CONCAT(tags.id, ',', tags.displayName)`

Comment: @Matthieu make this an answer.

Answer (score 6):

As advised by @Willa, I add my comment as an anwser :

GROUP_CONCAT allows you to concat multiple fields :

```
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.id, ',', tags.displayName)
```

The only difference with Stephan's answer is in case your code allows the same tag to be affected several times to one post OR if you JOIN sequence leads you to multiselect the same record in the tag table. In those case, my solution will return the same tags multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

On top of [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18845259/5418514)'s great answer, to prevent the same content showing up multiple times due to multiple JOIN's in your query **but you don't want the id to show in the output...**

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT
    tags.displayName,
    '||__', tags.id, '__||'
    SEPARATOR '\n'
)
```

And then loop over the result in the end removing everything between ||__ and __|| .

This example is for php:

```
$data = preg_replace("/\|\|__.*__\|\|/", '',  $data);
```