# Want to retrieve multiple rows on behalf of same user from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have four tables

```
ApplicantBasic
A_id    Username    Email                Password
1       Williams   williams@gmail.com    sdfds12231 

ApplicantProjects
A_id   ProjectTitle  Duration     Year
 1       ABC         3 months    2015
 1       BCD         6 months    2017  

Applicant ProfessionalInfo
A_id   Organization  Designation   Duration
 1       10Pearls     Internee      5 months
 1         TPS         SQA          7 months  

ApplicantCertification
A_id   CertificateName    Url       Year
 1       .Net Diploma   abc.com      2011
 1        CCNA           Cisco.com   2014
```

I want to retrieve username,email and password from ApplicantBasic table and retrieve all information from rest of the 3 tables like this

```
A_id  : 1
Username : Williams   
Email : williams@gmail.com
Password :sdfds12231 
ProjectTitle : ABC 
Duration : 3 months
Year 2015
ProjectTitle : BCD
Duration : 6 months
Organization : 10Pearls
Designation  : Internee
Duration : 5 months
Organiation : TPS 
Designation : SQA
Duration : 7 months
CertificateName : .Net Diploma
Url : abc.com 
Year  : 2011
CertificateName : CCNA
Url : Cisco.com
Year : 2014
```

How can i retrieve it using mysql?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18845259/3179169. You can use '\n' as separator.

Comment: can my desired result be possible using sub query?